# Can I store a unix timestamp in an int?

Tags: mysql

I want to use `INT` but I'm not sure what to put after the `INT` part.

There are 3 common ways to store date/time per this [link](http://www.richardlord.net/blog/dates-in-php-and-mysql), but I just want to use a simple INT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number after the `INT` simply describes how wide the columns should be when you select from them. **It does not constrain the range of values stored in that field**. An INT is an INT no matter what number you put after it.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

> Numeric Type Attributes
>
> MySQL supports an extension for optionally specifying the display width of integer data types in parentheses following the base keyword for the type. For example, INT(4) specifies an INT with a display width of four digits. This optional display width may be used by applications to display integer values having a width less than the width specified for the column by left-padding them with spaces. (That is, this width is present in the metadata returned with result sets. Whether it is used or not is up to the application.)
>
> The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be stored in the column. Nor does it prevent values wider than the column display width from being displayed correctly. For example, a column specified as SMALLINT(3) has the usual SMALLINT range of -32768 to 32767, and values outside the range permitted by three digits are displayed in full using more than three digits.

Comment: @pst Assuming you store the offset in minutes, you need a range of -720 - 780

Comment: @nickf Silly me. I was thinking of DATETIMEOFFSET in SQL Server. It seems MySQL relies on a separate field or custom approach. Nevermind :)

Answer (score 1):

A trick question!

Use [`TIMESTAMP` for UNIX timestamps](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) and use `DATETIME` for dates outside the `TIMESTAMP` range.

Happy coding.

Comment: @Chris Aaker UNIX timestamps have always been to refer to present and practical upcoming dates (without terribly much precision or care for human constructs like timezones ;-) -- I'm sure when 2038 is significantly closer the MySQL TIMESTAMP range will be expanded to 64-bits or more; just as the logical extension of a "normal" UNIX timestamp. Heck, COBOL is still about, but I sure do hope that the "current" systems in 2038 will be well past the current relational systems ;-)